# How to registerForContextMenu from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I'm displaying List of Message, using Activity that show ListView from Adaptar as show below.

I need to register ContextMenu menu in the ImageView inside the below `DiscussArrayAdapter` class.

if I just call `registerForContextMenu(arrowImage);` from `DiscussArrayAdapter` it will not accept it.

also, I don't know where to override the method `onCreateContextMenu`

My messageActivity as follows:

```
public class MessagesActivity extends Activity  {
        private ListView listView = null;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        private DiscussArrayAdapter adapter;
        private ListView lv;
@Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_discuss);

            registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                            DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

            adapter = new DiscussArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listitem_discuss);

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and I have `DiscussArrayAdapter` class:

```
public class DiscussArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<OneMessage>{

    private /*TextView*/EditText msgTextView;
    private  TextView sender;

    private LinearLayout wrapper;

    private SqlHelper dbHelper = null;
    private Context context;
    @Override
    public void add(OneMessage object) {

        dbHelper.addNewMessage(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    public DiscussArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.context=context;

        if (dbHelper == null) {
            dbHelper = new SqlHelper(context);

        }


    }

    public int getCount() {

        return  dbHelper.getContactsCount();
    }

    public OneMessage getItem(int index) {

        return dbHelper.getOneComment(index+dbHelper.lastRawID());
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_discuss, parent, false);
        }

        wrapper = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

        ImageView arrowImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.aquaplayicon);
    //  this .registerForContextMenu(arrowImage);
        OneMessage coment = getItem(position);

        msgTextView =/*(TextView)*/(EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.comment);
```

I have omitted rest of code for brevity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `context` menu functions are all defined for class `Activity`, they don't exist for the `Adapter` class.

So either you need to make your `adapter` a subclass of the `activity`, or you need to pass the `activity` to the `adapter` so it can call the register function, and the activity will need to handle the `context` menu (or pass the event on to the adapter to handle it).

Comment: I do pass the context of the "message" activity in the constructor of DiscussArrayAdapter, and than in the method "public View getView" I tried to call: context.registerForContextMenu(arrowImage); but it didn't work

Answer (score 4):

You must cast the context variable with Activity class:

```
private Context context;

public ExpandibleListViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {

    if (convertView == null) {
       ......
    }

    .........

    ((Activity)context).registerForContextMenu(convertView);

    return convertView;
}
```